# array within a switch javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, switch-statement

A little while ago I needed help with a complicated switch, but now I am substituting the direct variables for arrays. I thought it best to use a for statement, and it isn't displaying the results.

This is a side project for me, so please let me know if there are any aspects you see that could be improved.

```
<script>
var strMod=0;
var dexMod=0;
var conMod=0;
var intMod=0;
var wisMod=0;
var chaMod=0;

var strength = prompt("what is your strength?");
var dexterity = prompt("what is your dexterity?");
var constitution = prompt("what is your constitution?");
var intelligence = prompt("what is your intelligence?");
var wisdom = prompt("what is your wisdom?");
var charisma = prompt("what is your charisma?");

var abilities=[strength,dexterity,constitution,intelligence,wisdom,charisma];
var abiMod=[strMod,dexMod,conMod,intMod,wisMod,chaMod];


for (var i=0; i<abilities.length;i++){
switch(true){
    case (abilities(i)>=0 && abilities(i)<2 && abilities(i)!==null):
        abiMod(i)=-5;
        break;
    case (abilities(i)>=2 && abilities(i)<4):
        abiMod(i)=-4;
        break;
    case (abilities(i)>=4 && abilities(i)<6):
        abiMod(i)=-3;
        break;
    case (abilities(i)>=6 && abilities(i)<8):
        abiMod(i)=-2;
        break;
    case (abilities(i)>=8 && abilities(i)<10):
        abiMod(i)=-1;
        break;
    case (abilities(i)>=10 && abilities(i)<12):
        abiMod(i)=0;
        break;
    case (abilities(i)>=12 && abilities(i)<14):
        abiMod(i)=1;
        break;
    case (abilities(i)>=14 && abilities(i)<16):
        abiMod(i)=2;
        break;
    case (abilities(i)>=16 && abilities(i)<18):
        abiMod(i)=3;
        break;
    case (abilities(i)>=18 && abilities(i)<20):
        abiMod(i)=4;
        break;
    case (abilities(i)>=20 && abilities(i)<22):
        abiMod(i)=5;
        break;
    default:
        abiMod(i)= prompt("what is your"+ abilities(i) +"modifier?");
        break;
};
alert(abiMod(i));
};
</script>
```

Comment: You can't assign to a function call like `abiMod(i)=-5;`

Comment: Use the correct syntax to access elements of an array `abilities[i]`, `abiMod[i]`. Also, your code to solve the problem looks bizarre.

Comment: And check your Javascript console, it's probably reporting syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks quantastical and Alexandre for the correction. Barmar what so you mean? The I am getting into table top gaming and I am too lazy to do the basic arithmetic and will be developing a home website to log the character data, so having the standard switch with the ability to review the individual array variable would help simplify the code. Also I thought about turning the switch into a function, but wasn't sure how to adjust the variables accordingly.

Comment: [A javascript intro](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/javascript) or maybe [this one instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript) would be a good starting place.

Comment: Thanks whip dancer I will look into it, because I have been working with a number of basic javascript educational tools and reading as much as possible, but somethings are easier when you try to experience them like I am trying with this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using the switch statement, there is a common theme across all case and so a mathematical formula can be used instead.

Here is the revised code

```
for (var i = 0; i < abilities.length; i++) {
    if (abilities[i] !== null && abilities[i] >= 0 && abilities[i] < 22) {
       abiMod[i] = Math.floor(abilities[i] / 2) - 5;
    }
    else {
        abiMod[i] = prompt("what is your "+ abilities[i] +" modifier?");
    }
};
```

Comment: John, that looks way simpler. I need to learn more about the Math.floor, this was the second time it was suggested (last time was specifically with the switch). Thanks for the advise. On the flip side with the correction of the index caller the switch does work.

Comment: Having looked at it again, you are right so I've deleted that part. You are better off doing it as an IF statement if you use a switch with a constant rather than a switch with a variable.

Comment: looking at what I am going to try to be doing with this equation (which is making it into a function to be used periodically throughout the code)  it would be best if I used an equation like the one you made above. Thanks you for the advise!

Comment: It makes sense to place similar equations in a function. If you ever needed to tweak the equation in future then you only have to change it in one place rather than changing it all over.

Comment: That is what I was thinking John. I was going to reuse this modifier calculation based on future adjustments to the primary variables.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you need to access array indices via brackets, not parens.

```
for (var i=0; i<abilities.length;i++){
switch(true){
    case (abilities[i]>=0 && abilities[i]<2 && abilities[i]!==null):
        abiMod[i]=-5;
        break;
    case (abilities[i]>=2 && abilities[i]<4):
        abiMod[i]=-4;
        break;
    case (abilities[i]>=4 && abilities[i]<6):
        abiMod[i]=-3;
        break;
    case (abilities[i]>=6 && abilities[i]<8):
        abiMod[i]=-2;
        break;
    case (abilities[i]>=8 && abilities[i]<10):
        abiMod[i]=-1;
        break;
    case (abilities[i]>=10 && abilities[i]<12):
        abiMod[i]=0;
        break;
    case (abilities[i]>=12 && abilities[i]<14):
        abiMod[i]=1;
        break;
    case (abilities[i]>=14 && abilities[i]<16):
        abiMod[i]=2;
        break;
    case (abilities[i]>=16 && abilities[i]<18):
        abiMod[i]=3;
        break;
    case (abilities[i]>=18 && abilities[i]<20):
        abiMod[i]=4;
        break;
    case (abilities[i]>=20 && abilities[i]<22):
        abiMod[i]=5;
        break;
    default:
        abiMod[i]= prompt("what is your"+ abilities[i] +"modifier?");
        break;
};
alert(abiMod[i]);
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction it worked. Now I am off to make it more complex, but if anyone sees anything I can do differently I would love to improve by learning something new.